# Airflow Python path trying to be read does not exist resulting in ImportError

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, airflow

I'm running Airflow in docker and all runs smoothly except when I want to create a new dag using airflow libraries. More specifically I'm importing

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.operators import DummyOperator
```

but when compiled it shows this error stating that there is no name DummyOperator in that folder. But the thing is that my Python folder is in this path */home/daniel/.local/lib/python3.10*.

[Import Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1u9i.png)

How can I solve this problem?

I tried setting up the PYTHONPATH env variable in the local host and also add the path to the PATH variable. None of them result in any change.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of Airflow you may need to use the `DummyOperator` or the `EmptyOperator`.

Airflow >= 2.3.0

```
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
```

Airflow < 2.3.0

```
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
```

Prior to Airflow v2 the import statement is

```
from airflow.operartors.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
```